# Unable to add Cortana channel on my bot service app

Tags: botframework

I'm unable to enable the Cortana channel on my bot service app.  When the cortana channel page loads, all options are grayed out and only a "Cancel" option is present.  I have tried using an MSA account that I granted co-administrator rights to as well as my work/school account.

While I've found others that have had this issue, I haven't been able to find a resolution.

Comment: Try some of the workarounds mentioned in this GitHub article: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/3658

Comment: Cortana now uses the knowledge.store you need to register your skill over on that portal now. please try following [this walkthrough](https://help.knowledge.store/getting_started/index.html)

Comment: @JasonSowers That’s helpful to know. Thanks!